# Why does ubuntu crash after resume from suspend

Tags: wireless, keyboard, suspend, freeze, crash

I'll try to make the background/step-by-step as short as possible:

1. Install ubuntu on an old laptop so I could use it as a media center with Kodi.
2. Do all updates/configs to make it look good.
3. Want to enable wake from usb so I could wake the computer using a wireless keyboard.
4. Follow several different instruction manuals online (including this [one](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/220-ubuntu-resume-usb-hid)) but they don't work.
5. At some point during this (or this might be the case every time even before I started messing with configurations) Ubuntu started freezing when resuming from suspension.
6. Freezing happens every time. I can move the mouse for a few seconds before but can't click or use keyboard.
7. Ubuntu either crashes into a black screen with spooling repeating white text, crashes to log in screen, or simply sticks at which time I have to manually restart using the power button.
8. And just as I was writing this the first time, it also froze when I was looking at my network connection.
9. I'll include my [syslog](http://speedy.sh/sn3zR/syslog).

I tried to enable wake from suspend from USB using thes which didn't work. I had to resume by pressing the power button. On resuming I could move the mouse for a few seconds but clicking or using the keyboard didn't register and then Ubuntu crashed and rebooted to the login screen.

Comment: There are often problems with resuming from both suspending and hibernation. For me, suspending works for the system, but not for my graphics, so Ubuntu is working, I can hear sound, can type and could click, but the screen stays dead. I gave up and just disabled the suspend functionality to prevent the machine from accidentally suspending and not being able to wake up properly.

Comment: Could you use http://paste.ubuntu.com/ for the syslog? And did suspend not work before or after following random commands off of the internet?

Comment: I'm afraid we can't help you much without knowing the things you did. A good step in the right direction though would be to upload your syslog and xorg.0.log to http://paste.ubuntu.com and link them back here so we can take a look. Also, what graphics card do you have?

Answer (score 1):

If you start following random links around the web, it's a good thing if you make a [system back-up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) (you're definitely user type 4) before trying random stuff that ends up freezing your computer.

So unless you post an exact list of everything you tried to do, the answer to "Why?" is *impossible to answer*...

Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news.  **:-(**